# Sum over one dimension when using {Dataset,DataArray}.group_by

Tags: python, python-xarray

Apologies in advance that my "minimal example" has a three-dimensional array, but it is necessary to show the full force of the problem I am running into (because `groupby` will end up stacking two of the dimensions together when I only intend to sum over one of them):

**Context:**

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
ds = xr.Dataset()

ds['kind'] = (['layer', 'qpoint'], [
    ['gamma', 'other', 'selected', 'selected', 'other', 'other'],
    ['selected', 'selected', 'other', 'gamma', 'other', 'other'],
])

# for each layer and eigenmode, we have a probability distribution
#  over the qpoints.
probs = np.random.random((2, 18, 6))
probs /= probs.sum(axis=2, keepdims=True) # sum over qpoints is 1
ds['prob'] = (['layer', 'mode', 'qpoint'], probs)
```

**The goal:**

Perform some kind of sum along the `'qpoint'` dimension of `ds['prob']` over groups of equal `ds['kind']`, producing a DataArray with dims `['layer', 'mode', 'kind']`. (not necessarily in that order)

**My furthest attempt:**

I tried to solve this using `groupby` but I really don't know what I'm doing. I couldn't make heads or tails of how to use `GroupBy.sum` when I only want to sum over the `qpoint` dimension. (naively calling `groupby('kind').sum()` will sum over all layers and modes as well)

Eventually, I tried just using the GroupBy as an iterator, yet I still ultimately ran into problems trying to put all the data back together in the end.

```
pairs = ds.groupby('kind')

# I couldn't make heads or tails of how to use GroupBy.sum,
#  so I tried the more familiar concept of iteration.

# focus on the 'prob' DataArrays
pairs = [(kind, d['prob']) for (kind, d) in pairs]

# unstack them so that `qpoint` is a valid dimension to sum over.
# (this densifies the arrays in the process though, producing 2x18x6 arrays
#  that are mostly filled with nan; this seems kind of backwards...)
pairs = [(kind, d.unstack('stacked_layer_qpoint')) for (kind, d) in pairs]
pairs = [(kind, d.sum(dim='qpoint')) for (kind, d) in pairs]

# 'kind' got lost when we did the sum. add it back
arrays = [d.assign_coords(kind=kind) for (kind, d) in pairs]
```

At this point, each array looks like:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'prob' (mode: 18, layer: 2)>
array([[0.231093, 0.345689],
       ...
       [0.204913, 0.043868]])
Coordinates:
  * layer    (layer) int64 0 1
    kind     <U5 'gamma'
Dimensions without coordinates: mode
```

But even after all of that, I get the following error when I try to stick them back together, and I don't know how to resolve it. (I do want 'kind' to be a coordinate, but I don't know what it wants me to do!)

```
# xarray.core.merge.MergeError: unable to determine if these variables
#      should be coordinates or not in the merged result: {'kind'}
ds['kind-prob'] = xr.concat(arrays, dim='kind')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just mere seconds before posting this, I tried *purely on a whim* to change this code to use `groupby(...).apply(...)`.  To my amazement, my first attempt at using `apply` appears to have produced exactly what I wanted:

```
result = (
    ds.groupby('kind')
        .apply(lambda d: d['prob']
                         .unstack('stacked_layer_qpoint')
                         .sum(dim='qpoint')
        )
)
# result has dims: (kind: 3, mode: 18, layer: 2)
```

However, this still fails with `MergeError` if naively assigned to a new variable of `ds`.

<s>It turns out that this error is simply because I had set `kind` as a variable instead of a coordinate.  That can be corrected after-the-fact by using `set_coords` to "upgrade" `kind` into a coordinate:</s>

```
ds['kind-prob'] = result   # this would give MergeError

ds = ds.set_coords('kind')
ds['kind-prob'] = result   # ok now
```

**Edit:** Nope, that's a bad idea, too.  `result` has `'kind'` as a *dimension,* but after this assignment, the `'kind'` is merely a *coordinate.*  Perhaps the real issue here is that I am trying to have both a dimension and a variable share the same name, which simply is not supported.

---

I also discovered two more possible improvements to the definition:

- `DataArray.groupby` can take a `DataArray` containing the values to use for grouping (making it unnecessary to use `groupby` on the entire `Dataset`)
- <s>I can avoid the `unstack` by making nested calls to `groupby`.  The idea is to `groupby` each individual thing you want to have as a dimension in the output array.</s>

  - <s>This works because the original `layer` and `qpoint` coordinates are still there; if you inspect one of the arrays produced by the first `groupby`, you will see it has one dimension (`stacked_layer_qpoint`) but three coordinates (`stacked_layer_qpoint`, `layer`, `qpoint`).</s>
  - **Edit:** It turns out that nested groupby-apply is insanely slow compared to the solution using `unstack`, presumably because it puts a lot of pure python code (the lambdas) in a hot loop.

This results in the following:

```
kind_prob = (
    ds['prob']
        .groupby(ds['kind'])
        .apply(lambda d: d.unstack('stacked_layer_qpoint').sum(dim='qpoint'))
)
```

Comment: Actually, the code I posted here is now giving me the same `MergeError`.  It looks like I must've unwittingly made a change that broke it shortly after getting it to work. =(

Comment: Ahhhhh... The error isn't from `concat`.  It's from `Dataset.__setitem__`.